# Rank Order Analysis with Missing Values

Tags: missing-data, ranking

I have several survey questions that allow a respondent to choose their top three choices from a set of potential answers--basically "What is the most important, 2nd most important, 3rd most important." This leaves me with a rank order question containing several missing values since there are more than just three options to choose from.

I am aware of some of the traditional methods of analysis for rank order (i.e. Wilcoxon, Spearman, Friedman Test, etc.) but I believe that these all require every option to be ranked, not just a "top nth."

Are there any suggestions on the best way to analyze this type of data?

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach would be not consider the unranked options as all tied for last place. So if you have six options and only the top three are ranked the remaining three are tied for last. What you do next depends on your preferences for dealing with ties. One way would be to assign the average of the tied ranks so giving $\frac{4+5+6}{3} = 5$ for each of them. Another way is to break the ties at random.